# How i can fetch data conditionally in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to React, and im trying when in the parent component table row is selected, to provide props to the child Modal component, and inside this child component to fetch a data based on the provided props. I created a custom hook useFetch what stores the data, error, loading in state, and just return me a callback what i can call to fetch the data. Is there a way to fetch the data only when props change without using useEffect?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: No one can help you if you don't share any code.

Comment: @lharby Sorry, i updated the post.

Comment: Please post code as text and not as picture ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you'll need to use something like `useEffect` if you're retrieving data. Take a look at [React Query](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/examples/react/simple) for a fairly clean way to work with data in react. There are other solutions but as of 2023 react query seems to be a good option.